# Guitar Headphone pre-amp with output jack?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers, pre-amp

Ok, guys Ive tried to search the site for a similar question to no avail. Since I know little on the subject I will describe it and Im sure youl get the just.

I ocasionally play acoustic guitar in Church. All instruments go to the central mixer+amp. No special guitar amp whatsoever. Reference speakers no good. I need a mini-preamp to plug in my guitar, that works as a bluetooth emitter or has a headphone plug (to use as reference) and also has a regular output jack to go to the central mixer+amp. All Ive seen are wireless mini preamps but they dont have a regular output jack and the main mixer+amp does not have wireless reception.

Is there such a thing?? Excuse my poor techical knowledge and English.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those exist. Look for a '[guitar headphone](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/search.php?s=guitar%20headphone) amplifier' with a line output.  Some headphone amps [don't have a line out](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/amPlugCleanG2--vox-amplug-2-clean-headphone-guitar-amp), so make sure to check the specs.

Examples: [cheap one](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/GoGuitar--tc-helicon-go-guitar-portable-guitar-interface-for-mobile-devices), [another](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/GoGuitarPro--tc-helicon-go-guitar-pro-portable-guitar-interface-for-mobile-devices)

Comment: I have one of those Vox beasts, and they work well and fit your criteria, but you may find them to be noisy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after carefully inspecting the above shown examples thats not exactly what I need. Taking some time I could find these two, just want to be sure if they work the way I want and if you can think on a cheaper alternative.

https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/iRigHD2--ik-multimedia-irig-hd-2-guitar-interface-for-iphone-ipad-mac-and-pc

https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/iRigNanoRd--ik-multimedia-irig-nano-amp-mobile-micro-guitar-amp-and-ios-interface-red

Comment: Make sure those are usable without connecting a phone or computer.

Comment: and was there anything specific you missed in my suggestions?